# Password in Preferences 

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, preferences

I want to set the preferences of my application in the settings application. I have gone thru the documentation for creating preferences for iphone applications using settings.bundle . But the documentation only speaks of how to set the value and extract the values from the preferences. But in my settings application for my app I am using it for resetting my applications password . So I would require to pop-up an alert view if the new password and the confirm password isn't same . So how can I control the settings application from my application code to pop-up this alert view.For example, the safari application has it's preferences inside settings application . When u click on clear cookies , it pops up an alert view.Something similar to this I want to implement .

Cheers!

/ f0rz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't.

I would suggest having your settings in-app, so you have a little more control.